# O Formulário fica preso/Travado quando clico no datetimepicker

Tags: c#, winforms

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação e já fiz 90%, mas estou com um problema no controle datetimepicker.

Normalmente o seu formato é longo, mas tive mudar para 'time' e habilitei o `ShowUpDown` como `true`.

Quando eu clico no controle o formulário fica preso e não funciona mais nada e nem fecha.

Então eu tenho de fechar no Gerenciador de tarefas do Windows ou parar a depuração.

Como posso resolver isso?

Não tem nenhum evento associado, eu apenas, em modo gráfico, edito a hora da saída do visitante e para 12:45:00 por exemplo, em seguida clico no botão atualizar pegando o valor do controle através da propriedade nomeObjeto.Value.TimeOfDay; que é a propriedade de TimeSpan que preciso armazenar no banco de dados.

O problema é que quando eu mecho no contorle, os outros contorles não funcionam apenas ele, nem o botão atualizar responde ao click, mas o controle em questão continua permitindo mudar hora, minuto e segundo, é como se eu tivesse de tirar do modo de edição ou parar alguma terefa que o mesmo cria.

---

Segue o meu código do formulário, atentem apenas para o método do botão atualizar:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using ObjetoTransferencia.ControleVisitante;
using RegrasDeNegocio.CRUD;

namespace Intragh.Portaria
{
    public partial class FrmControleVisitante : Form
    {
        private readonly ControleVisitanteCRUD _controleVisitanteCrud;
        public FrmControleVisitante()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _controleVisitanteCrud = new ControleVisitanteCRUD();
        }

        private void FrmControleVisitante_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            controleVisitanteBindingSource.DataSource = _controleVisitanteCrud.GetAll();
        }

        private void btnNovo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FrmControleVisitanteCadastrar frmControleVisitanteCadastrar = new FrmControleVisitanteCadastrar();
            frmControleVisitanteCadastrar.ShowDialog();
            controleVisitanteBindingSource.DataSource = _controleVisitanteCrud.GetAll();
        }

        private void btnAtualizar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                var controleVisitante = controleVisitanteDataGridView.SelectedRows[0].DataBoundItem as ControleVisitante;

                if (controleVisitante != null)
                {
                    controleVisitante.ControleId = Convert.ToInt32(controleIdTextBox.Text);
                    controleVisitante.HoraSaida = horaEntradaDateTimePicker.Value.TimeOfDay;
                    controleVisitante.Observacao = observacaoTextBox.Text;

                    _controleVisitanteCrud.Atualizar(controleVisitante);
                }
                controleVisitanteBindingSource.DataSource = _controleVisitanteCrud.GetAll();

            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(exception.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Existem eventos atrelados a este controle?

Comment: coloque o código do seu form jovem

Comment: quando a tela estiver travada, pause a depuração do visual studio pra ver qual código estava sendo executado